# A question of probability of the random variable $X_n$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Consider a society of $n$ individuals. Assume that for every $1 \leq i < j \leq n$, the $i$-th individual is a friend of $j$-th individual with probability $n^{-2}$. Let $A_{ij}$ be the event that the $i$-th and the $j$-th individuals are friends. Assume that the collection of events $(A_{ij} : 1 \leq i < j \leq n)$ are independent. If $X_n$ denotes the number of friendships in the society calculate $P(X_n = k)$ , for every $k = 0,1,2, \cdots , \mathrm {etc}$.

I have found the answer to be $$\Bbb P \left (X_n = k \right ) = \binom {\binom {n} {2}} {k} \left (\frac 1 {n^2} \right)^k \left (1 - \frac 1 {n^2} \right)^{\binom {n} {2} - k}.$$

Is this correct? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well for starters you should try to deduce a relationship between the events $\{X_n=k\}$ and $A_{ij}$. Did you try any ideas?

Comment: I got a very weird answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let $Y_{i,j}$ be a random variable which is $1$ if $i,j$ are friends and $0$ otherwise. They are all independent and $\mathbb{P}(Y_{i,j} = 1) = n^{-2}$.

Moreover $X_n = \sum\limits_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} Y_{i,j}$.

Clearly $$ \mathbb{P}(X_n = k) = \sum \mathbb{P}(Y_{i,j} = a_{i,j} \space \space \forall i<j)$$
Where the sum is done over all the values of $a_{i,j}$ such that exactly $k$ of them are $1$ and all the others are $0$. (they are $\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{k} = \binom{\frac{n \cdot (n-1)}{2}}{k}$ terms)

Moreover, use independence to show $$ \mathbb{P}(X_n = k) = \sum \prod\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n} \mathbb{P}(Y_{i,j} = a_{i,j}) = \sum n^{-2k} \cdot (1-n^{-2})^{\frac{n \cdot (n-1)}{2}-k} $$
So the answer should be: $$n^{-2k} \cdot (1-n^{-2})^{\frac{n \cdot (n-1)}{2}-k} \cdot \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{k} $$

Comment: I have already mentioned that.